# Js prototype , setting name

Tags: javascript

I don't mean a name property, e.g

```
String.prototype.myFunc = function(){}

var myString = new String();
console.log(myString);
```

When you view the created function in the console, there is a `name:''`. I was wondering how we set this.

Comment: I don't see anything odd in the console. As per your code it must print `String {format: function, truncate: function, splitOnLast: function, contains: function, myFunc: function}`

Comment: I've taken a image snip of what I mean [console](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qziq2aegrrsz7t0/prot.png). In the image the Js match function has name:'match' , Im wondering how we can set this with our own function

Comment: @kadaj: Only from the OPs code, there should be no `format`, `truncate`, `splitOnLast` and `contains` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Use a named function:

```
String.prototype.myFunc = function myFunc(){};
```

Comment: Why would anybody downvote this?  It's correct, though there are browser oddities that make using named function expressions a little hairy.

Comment: @Pointy yes I know IE used to give all named function expressions local scope access. So if you were making expressions in global scope, you in turn had a bunch of global functions. True for IE6, I think it's fixed in at least 8 and up though.

Comment: according to [that Kangax article I linked](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/) IE8 is broken; I don't know about 9.

Comment: I just tested 9.0.8112.16421 and it's broke as well, geesh.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a function with a function declaration statement and then assign it to the prototype property of your choice:

```
(function() { // to keep the global scope clean
  function myFunc() {
    // whatever
  }

  String.prototype.myFunc = myFunc;
})();
```

You can in fact give a name to any function in a function instantiation expression, but [it's not a super-safe thing to do.](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/)

Answer (score 0):

You did you an anonymous function, whose [`name` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) is the empty string.

Either use a [named function expression](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/):

```
String.prototype.myFunc = function myNamedFunc(){};
```

or assign a function which you declared with a name:

```
function myNamedFunc() {};
String.prototype.myFunc = myNamedFunc;
```